# NGRX: error population

Tags: ngrx

I'm trying to populate network/business/whichever kind of related errors using ngrx. In order to do so I've added a field in my `IStore`:

```
export interface IStore {
  user: IUser;
  sources: ISourceRedux;
  errors: IError;
}
```

As you can see, I'm handling `user` state using these reducers:

```
export class UserReducer {
    private static reducerName = 'USER_REDUCER';

    public static reducer(user = initialUserState(), {type, payload}: Action) {
        if (typeof UserReducer.mapActionsToMethod[type] === 'undefined') {
            return user;
        }

        return UserReducer.mapActionsToMethod[type](user, type, payload);
    }

    public static USER_LOGIN = `${UserReducer.reducerName}_USER_LOGIN`;

    public static USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = `${UserReducer.reducerName}_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS`;
    private static userLoginSuccess(sourcesRdx, type, payload) {
        return Object.assign(<IUser>{}, sourcesRdx, payload);
    }

    public static USER_LOGIN_FAILED = `${UserReducer.reducerName}_USER_LOGIN_FAILED`;
    private static userLoginFailed(sourcesRdx, type, payload) {
        return Object.assign(<IUser>{}, sourcesRdx, payload);
    }

  private static mapActionsToMethod = {
      [UserReducer.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS]: UserReducer.userLoginSuccess,
      [UserReducer.USER_LOGIN_FAILED]: UserReducer.userLoginFailed,
  };
}
```

`USER_LOGIN` action is reached since I've set an effect:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  constructor(
    private _actions$: Actions,
    private _store$: Store<IStore>,
    private _userService: UsersService,
  ) { }

  @Effect({ dispatch: true })
  userLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType('USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this._userService.checkPasswd(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
        .map((user: any) => {
          return { type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: user };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return Observable.of({ type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_FAILED', payload: { error: err } });
        })
    );
}
```

So, when an error occurs I `USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_FAILED` action is thrown, so `userLoginFailed`.

By other hand I0ve created this ERROR related actions:

```
export class ErrorReducer {
  private static reducerName = 'ERROR_REDUCER';

  public static reducer(user = initialErrorState(), {type, payload}: Action) {
    if (typeof ErrorReducer.mapActionsToMethod[type] === 'undefined') {
      return user;
    }

    return ErrorReducer.mapActionsToMethod[type](user, type, payload);
  }

    public static ERROR_APPEARS = `${ErrorReducer.reducerName}_APPEARS`;
    private static error(sourcesRdx, type, payload) {
        return Object.assign(<IError>{}, sourcesRdx, payload);
    }

  private static mapActionsToMethod = {
      [ErrorReducer.ERROR_APPEARS]: ErrorReducer.error
  };
}
```

But how could I throw an `ERROR_REDUCER_APPEARS` action? When? Where?

I've tried to dispatch the action inside the user effect. Nevertheless, I don't know if it's a bad practice:

```
  @Effect({ dispatch: true })
  userLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType('USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this._userService.checkPasswd(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
        .map((user: any) => {
          return { type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: user };
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          this._store$.dispatch({ type: 'ERROR_REDUCER_APPEARS', payload: { msg: err.message } });
          return Observable.of({ type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_FAILED', payload: {} });
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

The answer is actually pretty simple:

***Make your error-reducer reduce the `USER_LOGIN_FAILED`-action.***

A reducer is responsible for it's slice of the app-state, but should **not** be limited to only reduce a subset of available actions.
Therefore, a reducer can reduce any action and multiple reducers can reduce the same action.

For example, if the `USER_LOGIN_FAILED`-action is dispatched in your user-effect
you can have the error-reducer populate the error-slice of the store and the user-reducer reset the user-slice of the store back to the initial state (or whatever else makes sense for that action). The user-reducer dos not necessarily have to react to `USER_LOGIN_FAILED`.

### Specific to your code

First, the main problem with your approach is that you define actions inside a reducer.
Secondly, you don't need an `ERROR_REDUCER_APPEARS`-action with what I assume you are trying to achieve.

*Effect:*

```
@Effect({ dispatch: true })
  userLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType('USER_LOGIN')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this._userService.checkPasswd(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
        .map((user: any) => {
          return { type: 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: user };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // you don't need to dispatch an additional action here
          return Observable.of({ type: 'USER_LOGIN_FAILED', payload: err });
        })
    );
```

Notice that I renamed your actions. The reason is that actions shouldn't be specific to a reducer.

Unfortunately this means that you have to re-write a whole chunk of your reducers:

*user-reducer:*

```
export class UserReducer {
    public static reducer(user = initialUserState(), {type, payload}: Action) {
        switch(type) {
            case 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS': {
                return Object.assign(<IUser>{}, user, payload);
            }
            case 'USER_LOGIN_FAILED': {
                // return initialstate or whatever makes sense.
                // or remove the case-statement if nothing should change in the user-slice
            }
            default: {
                return user;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*error-reducer:*

```
export class ErrorReducer {
    public static reducer(error = initialErrorState(), {type, payload}: Action) {
        switch(type) {
            case 'USER_LOGIN_FAILED': {
                return Object.assign(<IError>{}, error, payload);
            }
            default: {
                return error;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that `mapActionsToMethod` is intended to make your actions 'typesafe'.
In my example, you could do something like this:

*user-actions.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class UserActions {
    static USER_LOGIN = "USER_LOGIN";
    static USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS";
    static USER_LOGIN_FAILED = "USER_LOGIN_FAILED";
}
```

and then replace the string like this:

```
case 'UserActions.USER_LOGIN_FAILED': {
    return Object.assign(<IError>{}, error, payload);
}
```